# twitter app in messaging menu

Tags: 13.04, messaging-menu, twitter, friends-app

I've installed `friends-app` in my Ubuntu 13.04 but I can't see any `twitter` app icon under messaging menu.

How can I get twitter app icon in messaging menu in Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: I think you want to use the Unity Webapp for Twitter

Comment: Friends-App still doesn't have messaging menu support.